# Why would a specific comparison return records from a SQL Server Stored Proc but an IN clause containing the same value return nothing?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-in, in-clause

I have two Stored Procedures which are identical except for two things:

(a) One works (returns records) and the other doesn't (returns no records)

(b) The working one searches for a single match, whereas the nonworking one casts a wider net, including additional values in those being sought

The only differences (besides the SP names) between the two Stored Procedures are:

1)
Where the working Stored Proc contains this:

```
where UPPER(up.Unit) = 'ROCK BOTTOM'
```

...the nonworking Stored Proc contains this:

```
where UPPER(up.Unit) IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM')
```

2)

Where the working Stored Proc contains this:

```
where UPPER(up.Unit) = 'ROCK BOTTOM' and C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= @CalendarBegDate
```

...the nonworking Stored Proc contains this:

```
where UPPER(mp.Unit) IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM') and C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= @CalendarBegDate
```

3)

And finally, where the working Stored Proc contains this:

```
and Unit = ''ROCK BOTTOM'' and
```

...the nonworking Stored Proc contains this:

```
and Unit IN (''CHOPHOUSE'', ''CRAFTWORKS SC'', ''GORDON BIERSCH'', ''OLD CHI FRANCHISE'', ''OLD CHICAGO'', ''ROCK BOTTOM'') and
```

Why would searching for 'Rock Bottom' along with other values fail, while looking for that value alone succeed?

### UPDATE

At commenter Kritner's request, here are the Stored Procs in their entirety; the first one is the one that works:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'sp_ViewPriceMatrix_Variance_RockBottomRollup_RockBottom', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_ViewPriceMatrix_Variance_RockBottomRollup_RockBottom;  
GO
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_ViewPriceMatrix_Variance_RockBottomRollup_RockBottom]
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @SortBy varchar(20) 
AS
DECLARE 
@SQLstring varchar(max), 
@Statement varchar(8000), 
@ShortName varchar(50),
@ItemCode varchar(25), 
@PriceWeek varchar(30),
@LastPriceWeek varchar(30),
@Week int, 
@WherePriceWeek varchar(2000), 
@Price varchar(25),
@Contractprice int,
@CalendarBegDate datetime,
@CalendarEndDate datetime

create table #Temp
(
    Unit varchar(50),
    ShortName varchar(25),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    Description varchar(250),
    regionorder int,
    Contractprice varchar(50),
    Price varchar(25),
    Variance varchar(25),
    PriceWeek varchar(50),
    Week varchar(10)
)


-- create temp table
Select up.Unit, mm.ShortName,
up.ItemCode, Description=(Select Description from MasterProducts where ItemCode=up.itemcode), 
mm.regionorder, up.Contractprice 
into #TempContract From UnitProducts up 
Inner Join Unitmembers um on up.Unit=um.Unit and abs(um.pricesheet) = 1
Inner Join Members mm on um.memberno = mm.memberno
where UPPER(up.Unit) = 'ROCK BOTTOM' 


Select @CalendarBegDate = C.BeginDate From Calendar C where @BegDate between C.BeginDate and C.EndDate
Select @CalendarEndDate = C.EndDate From Calendar C where @EndDate between C.BeginDate and C.EndDate

-- get weeks and where clause
SET @WherePriceWeek = ' Where '

Declare GetPriceWeek Cursor For
Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, C.BeginDate 
From Calendar C 
where C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= @CalendarBegDate  
Order By 2 
Open GetPriceWeek
fetch next from GetPriceWeek into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin       
        Select @Statement = ('Alter Table #TempContract Add [' + @PriceWeek + '] numeric(8,2) ')
        exec (@Statement)
        IF(@WherePriceWeek<>' Where ')
        Begin
            SET @WherePriceWeek = @WherePriceWeek + 'or '
        End
        SET @WherePriceWeek = @WherePriceWeek + 'IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
        fetch next from GetPriceWeek into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
    end
Close GetPriceWeek
Deallocate GetPriceWeek


-- build member data by weeks
Declare GetMemberColumns Cursor For 
SELECT distinct ShortName,ItemCode
FROM #TempContract 
Order by ShortName,ItemCode
Open GetMemberColumns 
fetch next from GetMemberColumns into @ShortName,@ItemCode
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        Declare GetMemberPrice Cursor For
        Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, convert(varchar(20),
        cast(IsNull(mp.Price,0) as numeric(8,2))) as Price, 
        up.Contractprice 
        From MemberPrice mp 
        Inner Join UnitProducts up on mp.unit=up.unit and mp.itemcode=up.itemcode 
        Inner Join Unitmembers um on mp.memberno=um.memberno and mp.unit=um.unit and abs
(um.pricesheet) = 1
        Inner Join Members mm on mp.memberno = mm.memberno
        Inner Join Calendar C on mp.CYear=C.CYear and mp.Cweek=C.CWeek
        where UPPER(up.Unit) = 'ROCK BOTTOM' and C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= 

@CalendarBegDate 
and mm.ShortName = @ShortName and Mp.ItemCode = @ItemCode
        Open GetMemberPrice 
        fetch next from GetMemberPrice into @PriceWeek,@Price,@Contractprice
        while @@fetch_status = 0
            begin
                Print(@Price)
                Select @Statement = ('Update #TempContract Set [' + @PriceWeek  + ']=''' + 
IsNull(@Price,'0.00') + ''' where ItemCode=''' + @ItemCode + ''' and Unit = ''ROCK BOTTOM'' and 
[ShortName]=''' + @ShortName +'''')
                exec (@Statement)
                fetch next from GetMemberPrice into @PriceWeek,@Price,@Contractprice
            end
        Close GetMemberPrice
        Deallocate GetMemberPrice

        fetch next from GetMemberColumns into @ShortName,@ItemCode
    end
Close GetMemberColumns
Deallocate GetMemberColumns

--Select * From #TempContract 

-- final select statement
SET @Week = 0
SET @LastPriceWeek = ''
SET @SQLstring = ''

Declare SetPriceWeekSQL Cursor For
Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, C.BeginDate 
From Calendar C 
where C.BeginDate between @CalendarBegDate and @CalendarEndDate 
Order By 2 
Open SetPriceWeekSQL
fetch next from SetPriceWeekSQL into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        SET @Week = @Week + 1 
        IF(@SQLstring='')
        Begin
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'Insert Into #Temp Select Unit, ShortName, ItemCode, 
Description, regionorder, Contractprice, IsNull('+
            '['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') as Price, (convert(decimal(10,3),''-0.001'')) as 
Variance, 
            '''+@PriceWeek+''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From 
#TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek

            IF(@SortBy='Members')
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, ShortName, '''', 
''zzzz'', '''', '''', ''0'' as Price, ''-0.001'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar
(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek
            End
            Else
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, '''', ItemCode, 
Description, ''1000'', Contractprice, ''0'' as Price, ''-0.001'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, 
''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek
            End
        End
        ELSE 
        Begin
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION '
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'Select Unit, ShortName, ItemCode, Description, 
regionorder, Contractprice, IsNull('+
            '['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') as Price, IsNull(convert(decimal(10,2),['+@PriceWeek
+'])-convert(decimal(10,2),['+@LastPriceWeek+']),''0.00'') as Variance, 
            '''+@PriceWeek+''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From 
#TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek

            IF(@SortBy='Members')
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, ShortName, '''', 
''zzzz'', '''', '''', ''0'' as Price, ''0'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar
(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract Where IsNull(['+@LastPriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' or 
IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
            End
            Else
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, '''', ItemCode, 
Description, ''1000'', Contractprice, ''0'' as Price, ''0'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert
(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract Where IsNull(['+@LastPriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' 
or IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
            End
        End
        SET @LastPriceWeek = @PriceWeek
        fetch next from SetPriceWeekSQL into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
    end
Close SetPriceWeekSQL 
Deallocate SetPriceWeekSQL 

Print(@SQLstring) 
Execute(@SQLstring)

Drop Table #TempContract 

IF(@SortBy='Members')
Begin
    Select 
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        convert(varchar(20),convert(decimal(10,2),Price)) as Price,
        sum(convert(money,Variance)) as Variance,
        VarianceAverage = convert(varchar(25),convert(decimal(10,2),(Select sum(convert
(money,Variance)) From #Temp Where ShortName=T.ShortName and Week=T.Week) / Replace(((Select count
(regionorder) From #Temp Where ShortName=T.ShortName and Week=T.Week)-count(Variance)),'0','1'))), 
        PriceWeek,Week
    From #Temp T
    Group By
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        Price,
        PriceWeek,Week  
    Order By Week,ShortName,Description
End
ELSE
Begin
    Select 
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        convert(varchar(20),convert(decimal(10,2),Price)) as Price,
        sum(convert(money,Variance)) as Variance,
        VarianceAverage = convert(varchar(25),convert(decimal(10,2),(Select sum(convert
(money,Variance)) From #Temp Where ItemCode=T.ItemCode and Week=T.Week) / Replace(((Select count
(regionorder) From #Temp Where ItemCode=T.ItemCode and Week=T.Week)-count(Variance)),'0','1'))), 
        PriceWeek,Week
    From #Temp T 
    Group By
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        Price,
        PriceWeek,Week  
    Order By Week,Description,regionorder 
End



Drop Table #Temp
```

...and this is the one that returns nothing:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'sp_ViewPriceMatrix_Variance_RockBottomExtended', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_ViewPriceMatrix_Variance_RockBottomExtended;  
GO
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_ViewPriceMatrix_Variance_RockBottomExtended]
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @SortBy varchar(20) 
AS
DECLARE 
@SQLstring varchar(max), 
@Statement varchar(8000), 
@ShortName varchar(50),
@ItemCode varchar(25), 
@PriceWeek varchar(30),
@LastPriceWeek varchar(30),
@Week int, 
@WherePriceWeek varchar(2000), 
@Price varchar(25),
@Contractprice int,
@CalendarBegDate datetime,
@CalendarEndDate datetime

create table #Temp
(
    Unit varchar(50),
    ShortName varchar(25),
    ItemCode varchar(50),
    Description varchar(250),
    regionorder int,
    Contractprice varchar(50),
    Price varchar(25),
    Variance varchar(25),
    PriceWeek varchar(50),
    Week varchar(10)
)

-- create temp table
Select up.Unit, mm.ShortName,
up.ItemCode, Description=(Select Description from MasterProducts where ItemCode=up.itemcode), 
mm.regionorder, up.Contractprice 
into #TempContract From UnitProducts up 
Inner Join Unitmembers um on up.Unit=um.Unit and abs(um.pricesheet) = 1
Inner Join Members mm on um.memberno = mm.memberno
where UPPER(up.Unit) IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM') 

Select @CalendarBegDate = C.BeginDate From Calendar C where @BegDate between C.BeginDate and C.EndDate
Select @CalendarEndDate = C.EndDate From Calendar C where @EndDate between C.BeginDate and C.EndDate

-- get weeks and where clause
SET @WherePriceWeek = ' Where '

Declare GetPriceWeek Cursor For
Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, C.BeginDate 
From Calendar C 
where C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= @CalendarBegDate  
Order By 2 
Open GetPriceWeek
fetch next from GetPriceWeek into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin       
        Select @Statement = ('Alter Table #TempContract Add [' + @PriceWeek + '] numeric(8,2) ')
        exec (@Statement)
        IF(@WherePriceWeek<>' Where ')
        Begin
            SET @WherePriceWeek = @WherePriceWeek + 'or '
        End
        SET @WherePriceWeek = @WherePriceWeek + 'IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
        fetch next from GetPriceWeek into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
    end
Close GetPriceWeek
Deallocate GetPriceWeek

-- build member data by weeks
Declare GetMemberColumns Cursor For 
SELECT distinct ShortName,ItemCode
FROM #TempContract 
Order by ShortName,ItemCode
Open GetMemberColumns 
fetch next from GetMemberColumns into @ShortName,@ItemCode
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        Declare GetMemberPrice Cursor For
        Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, convert(varchar(20),
        cast(IsNull(mp.Price,0) as numeric(8,2))) as Price, 
        up.Contractprice 
        From MemberPrice mp 
        Inner Join UnitProducts up on mp.unit=up.unit and mp.itemcode=up.itemcode 
        Inner Join Unitmembers um on mp.memberno=um.memberno and mp.unit=um.unit and abs
(um.pricesheet) = 1
        Inner Join Members mm on mp.memberno = mm.memberno
        Inner Join Calendar C on mp.CYear=C.CYear and mp.Cweek=C.CWeek
        where UPPER(mp.Unit) IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO', 'ROCK BOTTOM') and C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >= @CalendarBegDate 
and mm.ShortName = @ShortName and Mp.ItemCode = @ItemCode
        Open GetMemberPrice 
        fetch next from GetMemberPrice into @PriceWeek,@Price,@Contractprice
        while @@fetch_status = 0
            begin
                Print(@Price)
                Select @Statement = ('Update #TempContract Set [' + @PriceWeek  + ']=''' + 
IsNull(@Price,'0.00') + ''' where ItemCode=''' + @ItemCode + ''' and Unit IN (''CHOPHOUSE'', ''CRAFTWORKS SC'', ''GORDON BIERSCH'', ''OLD CHI FRANCHISE'', ''OLD CHICAGO'', ''ROCK BOTTOM'') and 
[ShortName]=''' + @ShortName +'''')
                exec (@Statement)
                fetch next from GetMemberPrice into @PriceWeek,@Price,@Contractprice
            end
        Close GetMemberPrice
        Deallocate GetMemberPrice

        fetch next from GetMemberColumns into @ShortName,@ItemCode
    end
Close GetMemberColumns
Deallocate GetMemberColumns

--Select * From #TempContract 

-- final select statement
SET @Week = 0
SET @LastPriceWeek = ''
SET @SQLstring = ''

Declare SetPriceWeekSQL Cursor For
Select [PriceWeek] = C.Description, C.BeginDate 
From Calendar C 
where C.BeginDate between @CalendarBegDate and @CalendarEndDate 
Order By 2 
Open SetPriceWeekSQL
fetch next from SetPriceWeekSQL into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        SET @Week = @Week + 1 
        IF(@SQLstring='')
        Begin
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'Insert Into #Temp Select Unit, ShortName, ItemCode, 
Description, regionorder, Contractprice, IsNull('+
            '['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') as Price, (convert(decimal(10,3),''-0.001'')) as 
Variance, 
            '''+@PriceWeek+''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From 
#TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek

            IF(@SortBy='Members')
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, ShortName, '''', 
''zzzz'', '''', '''', ''0'' as Price, ''-0.001'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar
(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek
            End
            Else
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, '''', ItemCode, 
Description, ''1000'', Contractprice, ''0'' as Price, ''-0.001'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, 
''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek
            End
        End
        ELSE 
        Begin
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION '
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'Select Unit, ShortName, ItemCode, Description, 
regionorder, Contractprice, IsNull('+
            '['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') as Price, IsNull(convert(decimal(10,2),['+@PriceWeek
+'])-convert(decimal(10,2),['+@LastPriceWeek+']),''0.00'') as Variance, 
            '''+@PriceWeek+''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From 
#TempContract'+@WherePriceWeek

            IF(@SortBy='Members')
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, ShortName, '''', 
''zzzz'', '''', '''', ''0'' as Price, ''0'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert(varchar
(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract Where IsNull(['+@LastPriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' or 
IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
            End
            Else
            Begin
                SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' UNION Select Unit, '''', ItemCode, 
Description, ''1000'', Contractprice, ''0'' as Price, ''0'' as Variance, '''' as PriceWeek, ''WK'+convert
(varchar(2),@Week)+''' as Week From #TempContract Where IsNull(['+@LastPriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' 
or IsNull(['+@PriceWeek+'],''0.00'') <> ''999.99'' '
            End
        End
        SET @LastPriceWeek = @PriceWeek
        fetch next from SetPriceWeekSQL into @PriceWeek, @BegDate
    end
Close SetPriceWeekSQL 
Deallocate SetPriceWeekSQL 

Print(@SQLstring) 
Execute(@SQLstring)

Drop Table #TempContract 

IF(@SortBy='Members')
Begin
    Select 
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        convert(varchar(20),convert(decimal(10,2),Price)) as Price,
        sum(convert(money,Variance)) as Variance,
        VarianceAverage = convert(varchar(25),convert(decimal(10,2),(Select sum(convert
(money,Variance)) From #Temp Where ShortName=T.ShortName and Week=T.Week) / Replace(((Select count
(regionorder) From #Temp Where ShortName=T.ShortName and Week=T.Week)-count(Variance)),'0','1'))), 
        PriceWeek,Week
    From #Temp T
    Group By
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        Price,
        PriceWeek,Week  
    Order By Week,ShortName,Description
End
ELSE
Begin
    Select 
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        convert(varchar(20),convert(decimal(10,2),Price)) as Price,
        sum(convert(money,Variance)) as Variance,
        VarianceAverage = convert(varchar(25),convert(decimal(10,2),(Select sum(convert
(money,Variance)) From #Temp Where ItemCode=T.ItemCode and Week=T.Week) / Replace(((Select count
(regionorder) From #Temp Where ItemCode=T.ItemCode and Week=T.Week)-count(Variance)),'0','1'))), 
        PriceWeek,Week
    From #Temp T 
    Group By
        Unit,
        ShortName,
        ItemCode,
        Description,
        regionorder,
        Contractprice,
        Price,
        PriceWeek,Week  
    Order By Week,Description,regionorder 
End



Drop Table #Temp
```

Comment: I don't understand, you have the same where clause portion provided twice?  Can you just post the procs instead of breaking out by their differences?  Including parameters and entirety of from clause?

Comment: Okay, but they are long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another difference in the two queries...

First query:

```
 where UPPER(up.Unit) = 'ROCK BOTTOM' and C.BeginDate <= @CalendarEndDate and C.EndDate >=
```

Second query:

```
 where UPPER(mp.Unit) IN ('CHOPHOUSE', 'CRAFTWORKS SC', 'GORDON BIERSCH', 'OLD CHI FRANCHISE', 'OLD CHICAGO',
```

You're referencing a different table. Does that make a difference? Notice in the first (working) query you reference `up` and the second is `mp`.

Comment: Good catch; when CodeCompare showed that line as different, I saw the obvious but not the not-so-obvious.